# Autodesk Forge Viewer what is the url for the viewer files (i.e. viewer3D.min.js) for version 2?

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the extractor sample node.js server as my guide and am converting it to a java app using v2 of the API
I know the v1 files are located at
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js

Is there also a url for v2?

looking for js and files for res/environments/ res/textures/ res/locales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The v1 version in the URL is misleading here in the context of the viewer. You should better use this url instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.9/style.min.css"/>
<script src="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.9/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/2.9/viewer3D.min.js"</script>
```

The current version number for the viewer is v2.9. In the most recent releases of the viewer, you also need to include the three.js library, otherwise you'll get some problem.